# Convert time interval given in seconds into more human readable form

Tags: javascript, datetime, time

I need a code snippet for converting amount of time given by number of seconds into some human readable form. The function should receive a number and output a string like this:

```
34 seconds 
12 minutes 
4 hours 
5 days 
4 months
1 year
```

No formatting required, hard-coded format will go.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert milliseconds into human readable form?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/175554/how-to-convert-milliseconds-into-human-readable-form)

Comment: yes and no, I was thinking there is a good JavaScript solution for this...

Comment: Seconds is a human readable form.

Comment: Well, "213123 seconds" is not so readable. You can propose a better title

Answer (score 78, accepted):

With help of Royi we've got code that **outputs time interval in a human readable form**:

```
function millisecondsToStr (milliseconds) {
    // TIP: to find current time in milliseconds, use:
    // var  current_time_milliseconds = new Date().getTime();

    function numberEnding (number) {
        return (number > 1) ? 's' : '';
    }

    var temp = Math.floor(milliseconds / 1000);
    var years = Math.floor(temp / 31536000);
    if (years) {
        return years + ' year' + numberEnding(years);
    }
    //TODO: Months! Maybe weeks? 
    var days = Math.floor((temp %= 31536000) / 86400);
    if (days) {
        return days + ' day' + numberEnding(days);
    }
    var hours = Math.floor((temp %= 86400) / 3600);
    if (hours) {
        return hours + ' hour' + numberEnding(hours);
    }
    var minutes = Math.floor((temp %= 3600) / 60);
    if (minutes) {
        return minutes + ' minute' + numberEnding(minutes);
    }
    var seconds = temp % 60;
    if (seconds) {
        return seconds + ' second' + numberEnding(seconds);
    }
    return 'less than a second'; //'just now' //or other string you like;
}
```

Comment: This is wrong. 
For the time like '3 day 0 hour 50 minutes 36 seconds', it only gets '3 day', because it returns when hour is coincidentailly "0".

Comment: TO make it more relevant if the value is not 0 then need to concat with the varible. for i.e.  let returnText = ''; if (days && days !== 0) {
        returntext += days + ' day' + numberEnding(days);
    }

Comment: @user2909913 It in facts return when day is not 0 and not when hours is 0, so it basically floors the result to the nearest unit (which in some case might be desirable because it's much shorter in all cases)

Answer (score 89):

```
 function secondsToString(seconds)
{
var numyears = Math.floor(seconds / 31536000);
var numdays = Math.floor((seconds % 31536000) / 86400); 
var numhours = Math.floor(((seconds % 31536000) % 86400) / 3600);
var numminutes = Math.floor((((seconds % 31536000) % 86400) % 3600) / 60);
var numseconds = (((seconds % 31536000) % 86400) % 3600) % 60;
return numyears + " years " +  numdays + " days " + numhours + " hours " + numminutes + " minutes " + numseconds + " seconds";

}
```

Comment: Thanks! If you add checking for plural(year/years) it would be perfect!

Comment: Thanks for your help, Royi. See my answer below which answers my question completely

Comment: and the magic numbers: `secondsInAYear = 31536000; secondsInADay = 86400; secondsInAnHour = 3600; secondsInAMinute = 60;`

Comment: Note: This doesn't take into account leap years, and only provides the values as a "span of time".

Comment: `(((seconds % 31536000) % 86400) % 3600) % 60  === seconds % 60` so you can save some bits that will die in your cpu 

    `var numyears = Math.floor(seconds / 31536000);
    var numdays = Math.floor((seconds % 31536000) / 86400);
    var numhours = Math.floor((seconds % 86400) / 3600);
    var numminutes = Math.floor((seconds % 3600) / 60);
    var numseconds = seconds % 60;`

Answer (score 66):

If you are interested in an existing javascript library that does the job very well, you may want to check [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

More specifically, the relevant moment.js piece for your question is [durations](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/).

Here are some examples of how you can take advantage of it to achieve your task:

```
var duration = moment.duration(31536000);

// Using the built-in humanize function:
console.log(duration.humanize());   // Output: "9 hours"
console.log(duration.humanize(true));   // Output: "in 9 hours"
```

moment.js has built-in support for 50+ human languages, so if you use the `humanize()` method you get multi-language support for free.

If you want to display the exact time information, you can take advantage of the [moment-precise-range](https://github.com/codebox/moment-precise-range) plug-in for moment.js that was created exactly for this purpose:

```
console.log(moment.preciseDiff(0, 39240754000);
// Output: 1 year 2 months 30 days 5 hours 12 minutes 34 seconds
```

One thing to note is that currently moment.js does not support weeks / days (in week) for duration object.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It's quite imprecise. `moment.duration(40, 'seconds')` yields `'a few seconds'`. `moment.duration(45, 'seconds')` yields `'a minute'`. [see this Feature request](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/348)

Comment: moment.js is [deprecated](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/) since 2020. A useful currently maintained library for this would be [humanize-duration](https://github.com/EvanHahn/HumanizeDuration.js).

Answer (score 43):

Took a swing based on @Royi's response:

```
/**
 * Translates seconds into human readable format of seconds, minutes, hours, days, and years
 * 
 * @param  {number} seconds The number of seconds to be processed
 * @return {string}         The phrase describing the amount of time
 */
function forHumans ( seconds ) {
    var levels = [
        [Math.floor(seconds / 31536000), 'years'],
        [Math.floor((seconds % 31536000) / 86400), 'days'],
        [Math.floor(((seconds % 31536000) % 86400) / 3600), 'hours'],
        [Math.floor((((seconds % 31536000) % 86400) % 3600) / 60), 'minutes'],
        [(((seconds % 31536000) % 86400) % 3600) % 60, 'seconds'],
    ];
    var returntext = '';

    for (var i = 0, max = levels.length; i < max; i++) {
        if ( levels[i][0] === 0 ) continue;
        returntext += ' ' + levels[i][0] + ' ' + (levels[i][0] === 1 ? levels[i][1].substr(0, levels[i][1].length-1): levels[i][1]);
    };
    return returntext.trim();
}
```

Nice thing about mine is that there is no repetitive `if`s, and won't give you **0 years 0 days 30 minutes 1 second** for example.

For example:

`forHumans(60)` outputs `1 minute`

`forHumans(3600)` outputs `1 hour`

and `forHumans(13559879)` outputs `156 days 22 hours 37 minutes 59 seconds`

Comment: How would you make it more english friendly, like `forHumans(13559879)` -> `156 days, 22 hours, 37 minutes, and 59 seconds`? This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Link broken now

Answer (score 16):

Try following:

```
seconds = ~~(milliseconds / 1000);
minutes = ~~(seconds / 60);
hours = ~~(minutes / 60);
days = ~~(hours / 24);
weeks = ~~(days / 7);
year = ~~(days / 365);
```

Note:

- A usual year has 365 days. A leap year has 366 days, so you need additional check if this is an issue for you.
- The similar problem with daylight saving. Some days have 23 and some 25 hours when time's changed.

Conclusion: this is a rude but small and simple snippet :)

Comment: Rewritten your code a bit according to bemchmark tests showing `parseInt` is too slow

Comment: This does not work.  For instance, if milliseconds is 300000 (5 minutes) then this gives milliseconds=300000, seconds=300, minutes=5, which is not the output the OP requested.  https://jsfiddle.net/yp6fcacs/

Answer (score 15):

Way more simple and readable.

```
milliseconds = 12345678;
mydate=new Date(milliseconds);
humandate=mydate.getUTCHours()+" hours, "+mydate.getUTCMinutes()+" minutes and "+mydate.getUTCSeconds()+" second(s)";
```

Which gives:

> "3 hours, 25 minutes and 45 second(s)"

Comment: This is a very good answer, and if I needed to output a **date 'Anno Domini'**, this would be the accepted answer. Instead, I needed to transform a **time interval**, into string like `1 month ago`. Totally my fault, my question was not clear. Thanks to you it was noticed, and the question was updated.

Comment: Very interesting pitfall for those who have to deal with dates and time intervals. If we counted the epoch since 0, not since 1970, this problem would not exist.

Comment: Your code works  good until the interval is less than one year, and when **daylight saving is not taken into account**.

Comment: @Dan I did that on purpose. to account for daylight saving remove UTC from all the last line.

Answer (score 14):

```
millisToTime = function(ms){

    x = ms / 1000;
    seconds = Math.round(x % 60);
    x /= 60;
    minutes = Math.round(x % 60);
    x /= 60;
    hours = Math.round(x % 24);
    x /= 24;
    days = Math.round(x);

    return {"Days" : days, "Hours" : hours, "Minutes" : minutes, "Seconds" : seconds};
}
```

This will take milliseconds as an int, and give you an JSON object containing all the info you could need

Comment: Thanks for the function.  In my case, I have to change Math.round(x) to Math.floor(x) to get the numbers that I need.

Answer (score 10):

To Convert time in millisecond to human readable format.

```
 function timeConversion(millisec) {

        var seconds = (millisec / 1000).toFixed(1);

        var minutes = (millisec / (1000 * 60)).toFixed(1);

        var hours = (millisec / (1000 * 60 * 60)).toFixed(1);

        var days = (millisec / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)).toFixed(1);

        if (seconds < 60) {
            return seconds + " Sec";
        } else if (minutes < 60) {
            return minutes + " Min";
        } else if (hours < 24) {
            return hours + " Hrs";
        } else {
            return days + " Days"
        }
    }
```

[image: "Out Put Sample"]

Comment: I always liked this style best

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to @Dan / @ Royi for the logic. However the implementation doesn't build time string like XX days, XX mins. I adjusted their code a bit:

```
function millisecondsToStr( milliseconds ) {
    let temp = milliseconds / 1000;
    const years = Math.floor( temp / 31536000 ),
          days = Math.floor( ( temp %= 31536000 ) / 86400 ),
          hours = Math.floor( ( temp %= 86400 ) / 3600 ),
          minutes = Math.floor( ( temp %= 3600 ) / 60 ),
          seconds = temp % 60;

    if ( days || hours || seconds || minutes ) {
      return ( years ? years + "y " : "" ) +
      ( days ? days + "d " : "" ) +
      ( hours ? hours + "h " : ""  ) +
      ( minutes ? minutes + "m " : "" ) +
      Number.parseFloat( seconds ).toFixed( 2 ) + "s";
    }

    return "< 1s";
}
```

When one runs it

```
console.log("=", millisecondsToStr( 1540545689739 - 1540545684368 ));
console.log("=", millisecondsToStr( 351338536000 ));
```

The results look like:

```
= 5.37s
= 11y 51d 10h 2m 16.00s
```

Answer (score 5):

Adding to the myriad of methods, here's a cheap and short way to retrieve a human readable time with only a single time unit.

```
const timeScalars = [1000, 60, 60, 24, 7, 52];
const timeUnits = ['ms', 'secs', 'mins', 'hrs', 'days', 'weeks', 'years'];

const getHumanReadableTime = (ms, dp = 0) => {
  let timeScalarIndex = 0, scaledTime = ms;

  while (scaledTime > timeScalars[timeScalarIndex]) {
    scaledTime /= timeScalars[timeScalarIndex++];
  }

  return `${scaledTime.toFixed(dp)} ${timeUnits[timeScalarIndex]}`;
};
```

Example outputs:

```
getHumanReadableTime(512000);
getHumanReadableTime(5120000);
getHumanReadableTime(51200000);
getHumanReadableTime(51200000, 2);
getHumanReadableTime(51200000, 6);

/*

Output:
    '9 min'
    '1 hrs'
    '14 hrs'
    '14.22 hrs'
    '14.222222 hrs'

*/
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function millisecondsToString(milliseconds) {
    var oneHour = 3600000;
    var oneMinute = 60000;
    var oneSecond = 1000;
    var seconds = 0;
    var minutes = 0;
    var hours = 0;
    var result;

    if (milliseconds >= oneHour) {
        hours = Math.floor(milliseconds / oneHour);
    }

    milliseconds = hours > 0 ? (milliseconds - hours * oneHour) : milliseconds;

    if (milliseconds >= oneMinute) {
        minutes = Math.floor(milliseconds / oneMinute);
    }

    milliseconds = minutes > 0 ? (milliseconds - minutes * oneMinute) : milliseconds;

    if (milliseconds >= oneSecond) {
        seconds = Math.floor(milliseconds / oneSecond);
    }

    milliseconds = seconds > 0 ? (milliseconds - seconds * oneSecond) : milliseconds;

    if (hours > 0) {
        result = (hours > 9 ? hours : "0" + hours) + ":";
    } else {
        result = "00:";
    }

    if (minutes > 0) {
        result += (minutes > 9 ? minutes : "0" + minutes) + ":";
    } else {
        result += "00:";
    }

    if (seconds > 0) {
        result += (seconds > 9 ? seconds : "0" + seconds) + ":";
    } else {
        result += "00:";
    }

    if (milliseconds > 0) {
        result += (milliseconds > 9 ? milliseconds : "0" + milliseconds);
    } else {
        result += "00";
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is the Intl.RelativeTimeFormat API, which is supported in recent versions of Chrome and Firefox.

An few examples:

```
let rtf = new Intl.RelativeTimeFormat("en");
rtf.format(-1, "day"); // 'yesterday'
rtf.format(-2, 'day'); // '2 days ago'
rtf.format(13.37, 'second'); // 'in 13.37 seconds'
```

And there's a lot more in [this blog post](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/10/intl-relativetimeformat) and in [the proposal itself](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-intl-relative-time).

Comment: It's timestamp, not time interval.

Comment: "Convert time interval...into more human readable form" kinda sounds like a time interval

Answer (score 3):

Here is my take.

Feel free to play around with it in the [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/rikojivibe/1/edit?js,console).

```
// This returns a string representation for a time interval given in milliseconds
// that appeals to human intuition and so does not care for leap-years,
// month length irregularities and other pesky nuisances.
const human_millis = function (ms, digits=1) {
    const levels=[
      ["ms", 1000],
      ["sec", 60],
      ["min", 60],
      ["hrs", 24],
      ["days", 7],
      ["weeks", (30/7)], // Months are intuitively around 30 days
      ["months", 12.1666666666666666], // Compensate for bakari-da in last step
      ["years", 10],
      ["decades", 10],
      ["centuries", 10],
      ["millenia", 10],
    ];
    var value=ms;
    var name="";
    var step=1;
    for(var i=0, max=levels.length;i<max;++i){
        value/=step;
        name=levels[i][0];
        step=levels[i][1];
        if(value < step){
            break;
        }
    }
    return value.toFixed(digits)+" "+name;
}

console.clear();
console.log("---------");
console.log(human_millis(1));
console.log(human_millis(10));
console.log(human_millis(100));
console.log(human_millis(1000));
console.log(human_millis(1000*60));
console.log(human_millis(1000*60*60));
console.log(human_millis(1000*60*60*24));
console.log(human_millis(1000*60*60*24*7));
console.log(human_millis(1000*60*60*24*30));
console.log(human_millis(1000*60*60*24*365));
console.log(human_millis(1000*60*60*24*365*10));
console.log(human_millis(1000*60*60*24*365*10*10));
console.log(human_millis(1000*60*60*24*365*10*10*10));
console.log(human_millis(1000*60*60*24*365*10*10*10*10));
```

If you use Typescript type and cast to make it work

```
let name : string | number = "";
    let step : string | number =1;
    for(var i=0, max=levels.length;i<max;++i){
        value/= step as number;
        name=levels[i][0];
        step=levels[i][1];
        if(value < step){
            break;
        }
        
    }
```

Output:

```
"---------"
"1.0 ms"
"10.0 ms"
"100.0 ms"
"1.0 sec"
"1.0 min"
"1.0 hrs"
"1.0 days"
"1.0 weeks"
"1.0 months"
"1.0 years"
"1.0 decades"
"1.0 centuries"
"1.0 millenia"
"10.0 millenia"
```

Answer (score 2):

This function outputs seconds in this format : 11h 22m, 1y 244d, 42m 4s etc
Set the max variable to show as many identifiers as you want.

```
function secondsToString (seconds) {

var years = Math.floor(seconds / 31536000);
var max =2;
var current = 0;
var str = "";
if (years && current<max) {
    str+= years + 'y ';
    current++;
}
var days = Math.floor((seconds %= 31536000) / 86400);
if (days && current<max) {
    str+= days + 'd ';
    current++;
}
var hours = Math.floor((seconds %= 86400) / 3600);
if (hours && current<max) {
    str+= hours + 'h ';
    current++;
}
var minutes = Math.floor((seconds %= 3600) / 60);
if (minutes && current<max) {
    str+= minutes + 'm ';
    current++;
}
var seconds = seconds % 60;
if (seconds && current<max) {
    str+= seconds + 's ';
    current++;
}

return str;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With the help of Dan answer, I came up with this if you want to calculate the difference between the post created time (from DB it should be retrieved as UTC) and the users system time and then show them the elapsed time, you could use below function

```
function dateToStr(input_date) {
  input_date= input_date+" UTC";
  // convert times in milliseconds
  var input_time_in_ms = new Date(input_date).getTime();
  var current_time_in_ms = new Date().getTime();
  var elapsed_time = current_time_in_ms - input_time_in_ms;

  function numberEnding (number) {
      return (number > 1) ? 's' : '';
  }

  var temp = Math.floor(elapsed_time / 1000);
  var years = Math.floor(temp / 31536000);
  if (years) {
      return years + ' year' + numberEnding(years);
  }
  //TODO: Months! Maybe weeks? 
  var days = Math.floor((temp %= 31536000) / 86400);
  if (days) {
      return days + ' day' + numberEnding(days);
  }
  var hours = Math.floor((temp %= 86400) / 3600);
  if (hours) {
      return hours + ' hour' + numberEnding(hours);
  }
  var minutes = Math.floor((temp %= 3600) / 60);
  if (minutes) {
      return minutes + ' minute' + numberEnding(minutes);
  }
  var seconds = temp % 60;
  if (seconds) {
      return seconds + ' second' + numberEnding(seconds);
  }
  return 'less than a second'; //'just now' //or other string you like;
}
```

eg: usage

```
var str = dateToStr('2014-10-05 15:22:16');
```

Answer (score 1):

To show only what you need and not day 0, hours 0...

```
formatTime = function(time) {
        var ret = time % 1000 + ' ms';
        time = Math.floor(time / 1000);
        if (time !== 0) {
            ret = time % 60 + "s "+ret;
            time = Math.floor(time / 60);
            if (time !== 0) {
                ret = time % 60 + "min "+ret;
                time = Math.floor(time / 60);
                if (time !== 0) {
                    ret = time % 60 + "h "+ret;
                     ...
                }
            }           
        }
        return ret;
    };
```

Comment: I love it. It returns only part that are used (bigger than zero). btw. You cold remove space before "ms" cause other units don't have space before them.

Answer (score 1):

Following a similar approach to @Dan, I have modified @Royi Namir's code to output a string with commas and and's:

```
secondsToString = function(seconds) {
    var numdays, numhours, nummilli, numminutes, numseconds, numyears, res;
    numyears = Math.floor(seconds / 31536000);
    numdays = Math.floor(seconds % 31536000 / 86400);
    numhours = Math.floor(seconds % 31536000 % 86400 / 3600);
    numminutes = Math.floor(seconds % 31536000 % 86400 % 3600 / 60);
    numseconds = seconds % 31536000 % 86400 % 3600 % 60;
    nummilli = seconds % 1.0;
    res = [];
    if (numyears > 0) {
        res.push(numyears + " years");
    }
    if (numdays > 0) {
        res.push(numdays + " days");
    }
    if (numhours > 0) {
        res.push(numhours + " hours");
    }
    if (numminutes > 0) {
        res.push(numminutes + " minutes");
    }
    if (numseconds > 0) {
        res.push(numseconds + " seconds");
    }
    if (nummilli > 0) {
        res.push(nummilli + " milliseconds");
    }
    return [res.slice(0, -1).join(", "), res.slice(-1)[0]].join(res.length > 1 ? " and " : "");
};
```

It has no period so one can add sentences after it, like here:

```
perform: function(msg, custom, conn) {
    var remTimeLoop;
    remTimeLoop = function(time) {
        if (time !== +custom[0]) {
            msg.reply((secondsToString(time)) + " remaining!");
        }
        if (time > 15) {
            return setTimeout((function() {
                return remTimeLoop(time / 2);
            }), time / 2);
        }
    };
    // ...
    remTimeLoop(+custom[0]);
}
```

Where `custom[0]` is the total time to wait for; it will keep dividing the time by 2, warning the time remaining until the timer ends, and stop warning once the time is under 15 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Below will work for both past and future datetime, also have option to pass `locale`.

```js
function relativeTime(isoString, locale = "en") {
  const timestamp = Date.parse(isoString);
  const msPerMinute = 60 * 1000;
  const msPerHour = msPerMinute * 60;
  const msPerDay = msPerHour * 24;
  const msPerMonth = msPerDay * 30;
  const msPerYear = msPerDay * 365;

  const current = Date.now();
  let elapsed = current - timestamp;

  const sign = elapsed > 0 ? -1 : 1;

  elapsed = Math.abs(elapsed);

  const rtf = new Intl.RelativeTimeFormat(locale, { numeric: "auto" });

  if (elapsed < msPerMinute) {
    return rtf.format(sign * Math.floor(elapsed / 1000), "seconds");
  } else if (elapsed < msPerHour) {
    return rtf.format(sign * Math.floor(elapsed / msPerMinute), "minutes");
  } else if (elapsed < msPerDay) {
    return rtf.format(sign * Math.floor(elapsed / msPerHour), "hours");
  } else if (elapsed < msPerMonth) {
    return rtf.format(sign * Math.floor(elapsed / msPerDay), "days");
  } else if (elapsed < msPerYear) {
    return rtf.format(sign * Math.floor(elapsed / msPerMonth), "months");
  } else {
    return new Date(timestamp).toLocaleString(locale);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
relativeTime(new Date().toISOString()) //'2021-11-13T18:48:58.243Z'
-> now

relativeTime('2021-11-13T18:48:50.243Z')
-> 8 seconds ago

relativeTime('2021-11-14T18:48:50.243Z')
-> in 23 hours

relativeTime('2021-11-15T18:48:50.243Z')
-> tomorrow

relativeTime('2021-10-15T18:48:50.243Z')
-> 29 days ago

relativeTime('2021-12-15T18:48:50.243Z')
-> next month
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple implementation:

```
function formatDuration(seconds) {
  const time = {
    d: Math.floor(seconds / 86400),
    h: Math.floor(seconds / 3600) % 24,
    m: Math.floor(seconds / 60) % 60,
    s: seconds % 60,
  };

  return Object.entries(time).filter(val => val[1] !== 0).map(val => val[1] + val[0]).join('');
}
```

In use it will produce this:

```
>  formatDuration(65_535)
<• '18h12m15s'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution. Later you can split by ":" and take the values of the array

```
 /**
 * Converts milliseconds to human readeable language separated by ":"
 * Example: 190980000 --> 2:05:3 --> 2days 5hours 3min
 */
function dhm(t){
    var cd = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
        ch = 60 * 60 * 1000,
        d = Math.floor(t / cd),
        h = '0' + Math.floor( (t - d * cd) / ch),
        m = '0' + Math.round( (t - d * cd - h * ch) / 60000);
    return [d, h.substr(-2), m.substr(-2)].join(':');
}

//Example
var delay = 190980000;                   
var fullTime = dhm(delay);
console.log(fullTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a big fan of objects, so I created this from https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Seconds

Usage:

```
var human_readable = new TimeSeconds(986543).pretty(); // 11 days, 10 hours, 2 minutes, 23 seconds

;(function(w) {
  var interval = {
    second: 1,
    minute: 60,
    hour: 3600,
    day: 86400,
    week: 604800,
    month: 2629744, // year / 12
    year: 31556930 // 365.24225 days
  };

  var TimeSeconds = function(seconds) { this.val = seconds; };

  TimeSeconds.prototype.seconds = function() { return parseInt(this.val); };
  TimeSeconds.prototype.minutes = function() { return parseInt(this.val / interval.minute); };
  TimeSeconds.prototype.hours = function() { return parseInt(this.val / interval.hour); };
  TimeSeconds.prototype.days = function() { return parseInt(this.val / interval.day); };
  TimeSeconds.prototype.weeks = function() { return parseInt(this.val / interval.week); };
  TimeSeconds.prototype.months = function() { return parseInt(this.val / interval.month); };
  TimeSeconds.prototype.years = function() { return parseInt(this.val / interval.year); };

  TimeSeconds.prototype.pretty = function(chunks) {
    var val = this.val;
    var str = [];

    if(!chunks) chunks = ['day', 'hour', 'minute', 'second'];

    while(chunks.length) {
      var i = chunks.shift();
      var x = parseInt(val / interval[i]);
      if(!x && chunks.length) continue;
      val -= interval[i] * x;
      str.push(x + ' ' + (x == 1 ? i : i + 's'));
    }

    return str.join(', ').replace(/^-/, 'minus ');
  };

  w.TimeSeconds = TimeSeconds;
})(window);
```

Answer (score 0):

I cleaned up one of the other answers a bit provides nice '10 seconds ago' style strings:

```
function msago (ms) {
    function suffix (number) { return ((number > 1) ? 's' : '') + ' ago'; }
    var temp = ms / 1000;
    var years = Math.floor(temp / 31536000);
    if (years) return years + ' year' + suffix(years);
    var days = Math.floor((temp %= 31536000) / 86400);
    if (days) return days + ' day' + suffix(days);
    var hours = Math.floor((temp %= 86400) / 3600);
    if (hours) return hours + ' hour' + suffix(hours);
    var minutes = Math.floor((temp %= 3600) / 60);
    if (minutes) return minutes + ' minute' + suffix(minutes);
    var seconds = Math.floor(temp % 60);
    if (seconds) return seconds + ' second' + suffix(seconds);
    return 'less then a second ago';
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function java_seconds_to_readable(seconds)
{
    var numhours = Math.floor(seconds / 3600);
    var numminutes = Math.floor((seconds / 60) % 60);
    var numseconds = seconds % 60;
    return numhours + ":" + numminutes + ":" + numseconds;
}
```

More simple way. You can years and days respectively.

Answer (score 0):

if you use node :

```
const humanize = require('human-date');

let yesterday = new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()-1));

console.log(humanize.relativeTime(yesterday)); //=> 1 day ago
```

Answer (score 0):

Since moment.js is [deprecated](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/) since 2020, a useful currently maintained library for this would be [humanize-duration](https://github.com/EvanHahn/HumanizeDuration.js).

Answer (score -1):

```
function secondsToTimeString(input) {
  let years = 0, days = 0, hours = 0, minutes = 0, seconds = 0;
  let ref = [31536000,86400,3600,60,1];
  for (let i = 0;i < ref.length;i++) {
    let val = ref[i];
    while (val <= input) {
      input -= val;
      if (i === 0) years++;
      if (i === 1) days++;
      if (i === 2) hours++;
      if (i === 3) minutes++;      
      if (i === 4) seconds++;      
    }
  return {years, days, hours, minutes, seconds};
  }
```