# Convert plain string date into required format and difference between two dates

Tags: javascript

I am getting date from XML but date is in plain string format. I would like to create the difference from today's date and time and the date and time which i am getting from xml.

For example i am getting date as a plain string in this format (2012-10-17T08:15:19.500-05:00).Now when i am doing difference with current date&time than i need to display something like this "2:hr,32min".

Any help/suggestion would be a great input.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
var myDate = new Date( '2012-10-17T08:15:19.500-05:00' ),
    newDate = new Date();
```

Browser results can vary when parsing dates. I have a test [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/kboucher/MgdQa/).

To get the difference between dates: `var diff = myDate - newDate;` and to convert that back to something useful: [Convert time interval given in seconds into more human readable form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8211744/convert-milliseconds-or-seconds-into-human-readable-form)

Comment: You'll have to convert back to string for that I think: `myDate.toLocaleString()`

Comment: Nope it display whole GMT thing. I need specific am and pm. i just wonder do i have to add extra logic?

Comment: Well, it displays the AM/PM in any case, though I'm not sure I understand. Why do you need AM/PM if you're looking for the difference between the two `Date` objects?

Comment: I do have to display date too. Date and difference both.

Comment: oops seems to me it throw NAN in ie when we get value in difference.

Comment: @Ghlitch::your code(jsfiddle) work on all browser but it display NAN in IE7.