# Best way to convert Milliseconds to number of years, months and days

Tags: java, android, date

I'm trying to convert a Milliseconds date to number of `years` `months` `weeks` and `days`.

For example: `5 months, 2 weeks and 3 days` or `1 year and 1 day`.

I don't want: `7 days` or `4 weeks` > this should be `1 week` and `1 month`.

I tried few ways but it always became something like `7 days and 0 weeks`.

My code:

```
int weeks = (int) Math.abs(timeInMillis / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 * 7));
int days = (int) timeInMillis / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)+1);
```

I have to add 1 to number of days because if I have 23 hours it should be 1 day.

Please explain how to convert it correctly, I think that there is more efficient ways to do it.

Comment: Use a `Calendar` and `setTimeInMillis()`

Comment: Can you give me an example please? I don't understand you correctly..

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html

Comment: OK, I set the date in the Calendar object. What should I do now? I want to know how many days,weeks,etc. in it, not the date itself.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I always use this for getting years etc from milliseconds and vice versa. Till now I've had no problems with it. Hope it helps.

```
import java.util.Calendar;

Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
//Set time in milliseconds
c.setTimeInMillis(milliseconds);
int mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH); 
int mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
int hr = c.get(Calendar.HOUR);
int min = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
int sec = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
```

Comment: I want to know how many days,weeks,etc. in it, not the date itself.

Comment: The milliseconds are calculated from 1 Jan 1970. So, you have final date and initial date. Making that logic to get days, months etc between two dates should not be hard.

Comment: I think it works. `int mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR)-1970;`
`int mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);`
`int mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)-1;` Tell me please if this is right.

Comment: It seems fine. I guess their should be no need of subtracting 1 day from the current days because that 1st Jan 1970 is also counted in the milliseconds.

Comment: Yes, but then if my time in millis is 86400000 (= 1 day) I get `2 days`. Do you know why?

Answer (score 9):

Thanks to [Shobhit Puri](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15461376/1866009) my problem was solved.

This code calculates how many months, days etc. are in a given time in milliseconds. I use it to calculate difference between two dates.

Full solution:

```
long day = (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24); // 24 hours in milliseconds
long time = day * 39; // for example, 39 days

Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTimeInMillis(time);
int mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR)-1970;
int mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH); 
int mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)-1;
int mWeek = (c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)-1)/7; // ** if you use this, change the mDay to (c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)-1)%7
```

Thank you again!

Comment: Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
//Set time in milliseconds
c.setTimeInMillis(milliseconds);
int mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH); 
int mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

Comment: Can you please explain how it works ie. how it returns the number of months?

Answer (score 4):

Source:[Convert time interval given in seconds into more human readable form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8211744/convert-milliseconds-or-seconds-into-human-readable-form)

```
function secondsToString(seconds)
{
var numyears = Math.floor(seconds / 31536000);
var numdays = Math.floor((seconds % 31536000) / 86400); 
var numhours = Math.floor(((seconds % 31536000) % 86400) / 3600);
var numminutes = Math.floor((((seconds % 31536000) % 86400) % 3600) / 60);
var numseconds = (((seconds % 31536000) % 86400) % 3600) % 60;
return numyears + " years " +  numdays + " days " + numhours + " hours " + numminutes + " minutes " + numseconds + " seconds";

}
```

Comment: and what about leap years?

Comment: where is months