# Java Date Conversion from Millisecond time

Tags: java, date, calendar

I am trying to calculate an offset time from a given date. I get the date as a String and parse it, and I have the offset in milliseconds. So for example

Date: 2015-08-18 00:00:00

Offset Time: 2678400000, which when applied to the date, it equals 2015-09-18 00:00:00, 31 days later.

My goal is to store each of the offsets (years/months/days/hours/minutes/seconds) in an array, so I can use it later.
However when I run this calculation using the Calendar class, I'm getting extra hours for some reason when called with offsetConverter(2678400000)

```
Output: 0 years 0 months 31 days 19 hours 0 minutes 0 seconds
```

Here is my code which I found and modified slightly from this link [Best way to convert Milliseconds to number of years, months and days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15460954/best-way-to-convert-milliseconds-to-number-of-years-months-and-days)

```
    public static int[] offsetConverter(long offset) {
    int[] delay =  new int[6];
    //delay 0-3 = years/months/days/seconds

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
    c.setTimeInMillis(offset);
    delay[0] = c.get(Calendar.YEAR) - 1970;
    delay[1] = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    delay[2] = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    delay[3] = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    delay[4] = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    delay[5] = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);

    for (int i = 0; i< delay.length; i++)
        System.out.print(delay[i] + " ");
    System.out.println();
    return delay;
}
```

If anyone sees what I'm doing wrong or has a simpler way to do this I would appreciate the help. Thanks!

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Milliseconds from `Date#getTime()` arrive in UTC timezone, but you instantiate calendar with default timezone, which is your local. This adds extra hours to your result.

To solve this issue, create a `Calendar` instance using UTC timezone:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDateTime.parse( 
    "2015-08-18 00:00:00".replace( " " , "T" )   // Convert input string to comply with ISO 8601 standard format, replacing SPACE in the middle with a `T`.
).plus( 
    Duration.ofDays( 31 )      // If you meant ( 31 * 24-hours ). 
    // Period.ofDays( 31 )     // If you meant 31 calendar-days. 
    // Period.ofMonths( 1 )    // If you meant a calendar-month.
)                              // Returns a fresh `LocalDateTime` object, distinct from original, per Immutable Objects pattern.
.toString()                    // Generate a string in standard ISO 8601 format to textually represent this object’s value.
```

> 2015-09-18T00:00

## Terms

The word “offset” here is a poor choice of terms. That word has a specific meaning in date-time handling: the amount of hours, minutes, and seconds a time zone is from UTC. See the Wikipedia entry for [*UTC offset*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset).

You seem to be concerned instead with a span of time unattached to the timeline. In the *java.time* classes such spans are called a `Duration` if in the scale of hours-minutes-seconds, and called `Period` if scaled in years-months-days.

## java.time

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes that supplanted the troublesome old date-time classes such as `Date`/`Calendar`.

### `Duration`

Convert your span of time from a count of milliseconds to a `Duration` object.

```
Duration d = Duration.ofMillis( 2_678_400_000L );
```

This happens to be 744 hours.

> d.toString(): PT744H

Out of curiosity, I checked the number of days in 744 hours, if we define “days” to be chunks of 24-hours.

> d.toDaysPart(): 31

So it seems you really intend a month or a period of 31 days. Either way, Java has classes for that.

If you really want: ( 31 * 24 hours ), then do use a `Duration`. But construct the `Duration` object with more self-documenting code.

```
Duration d = Duration.ofDays( 31 ) ;  // Exact same effect as `Duration.ofMillis( 2_678_400_000L )` but more clear as to your intention.
```

### ISO 8601

Your input string almost complies with ISO 8601 standard for date-time formats. The *java.time* classes use the standard formats by default when parsing/generating strings.

Convert your string to comply. Replace the SPACE in the middle with a `T`.

```
String input = "2015-08-18 00:00:00".replace( " " , "T" ) ;
```

> 2015-08-18T00:00:00

### `LocalDateTime`

Parse your input as a [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) as your input lacks an indicator of [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) or [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone).

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input ) ;
```

> ldt.toString(): 2015-08-18T00:00

Add your `Duration` object to get a new fresh [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html). The *java.time* classes use [immutable objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) so the original object is left intact.

```
LocalDateTime thirtyOneTimes24HoursLaterLdt = ldt.plus( d ) ;  // Adding a span-of-time to our `LocalDateTime` object to get another `LocalDateTime` object.
```

> thirtyOneTimes24HoursLaterLdt.toString(): 2015-09-18T00:00

Be aware that `LocalDateTime` does *not* represent an actual moment, a specific point on the timeline. Without the context of a time zone or offset-from-UTC, it is only a rough idea about *potential* moments along a range of about 26-27 hours.

### `ZonedDateTime`

If you know for certain your input string was meant to represent a moment in a particular zone, apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime` object (an actual moment).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone( z ) ;  // Now we have determined an actual moment, a point on the timeline.
```

> zdt.toString(): 2015-08-18T00:00+12:00[Pacific/Auckland]

You can add your `Duration` if you do not care about dates (whole days on the calendar).

```
ZonedDateTime thirtyOneTimes24HoursLaterZdt = zdt.plus( d ) ;
```

> thirtyOneTimes24HoursLaterZdt.toString(): 2015-09-18T00:00+12:00[Pacific/Auckland]

If your business logic was really meant to be thirty-one days on the calendar, use a `Period`.

```
ZonedDateTime thirtyOneDaysLater = zdt.plus( Period.ofDays( 31 ) ) ;
```

> thirtyOneDaysLater.toString(): 2015-09-18T00:00+12:00[Pacific/Auckland]

If your business logic is really intending a calendar month rather than a specific number of days, use a different `Period`. The class makes adjustments as needed to handle various months’ length ([read the doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#plusMonths-long-) and follow [that doc’s link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#plusMonths-long-)).

```
ZonedDateTime monthLater = zdt.plus( Period.ofMonths( 1 ) ) ;
```

> monthLater.toString(): 2015-09-18T00:00+12:00[Pacific/Auckland]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Using a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later, you may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. No need for strings nor java.sql.* classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).