# Dynamically pass random javascript array value to html img src

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'd like to dynamically pass an array value (in this case, String `"../name1.jpg"` or `"../name2.jpg"`) to the img src `<img src="here">`. Each time you hover over "Class of 2013", a random image will fade in, then fade out.

Is that possible to pass in a value by calling it as such? `<img src="getImages();` ?

How would you do it?

```
var ImgArray = new Array();
ImgArray[0] = "../name1.jpg";
ImgArray[1] = "../name2.jpg";

$(document).ready(function() {
    show();
});

function show(){
    $(".box").hover(
        function(){ $(this).find(".overlay").fadeIn(); } ,
        function(){ $(this).find(".overlay").fadeOut(); }
    );        
}

function getImages() {
    int i = Math.random() * (max - min) + min;          
    return ImgArray[i];
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="box">
    Class of 2013:
    <div class="overlay"> <!-- Put images to display here...--> 
        <img src="getImages();" alt="image to be displayed" />
    </div>
</div>​
```

Thank you

---

EDIT: Current Code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">     
        var ITLP = new Array();
        ITLP[0] = "/corp/itlp/ITLP%20Bios/DanTurcotte.jpg";
        ITLP[1] = "/corp/itlp/ITLP%20Bios/gomezwilmann.jpg";


        $(document).ready(function() {
            showimg();
        });


        function showimg()
            {
                $(".box > .overlay > img").attr("src",getImages());
                $(".box").hover(
                    function(){ $(this).find(".overlay").fadeIn(); } ,
                    function(){ $(this).find(".overlay").fadeOut(); }
                );        
            }

        function getImages() {
            int i = Math.abs(Math.random());            
            return ITLP[0];             
        }

    </script>


</head> 
<body>

    <div class="box">
        Class of 2013:
        <div class="overlay"> <!-- Put images to display here...-->                 
            <img src="" border="none"/>     
        </div>  
    </div>​

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer the classic way:

```
    $(".box > .overlay > img").attr("src",getImages());
```

Extension:

```
function show()
{
    $(".box > .overlay > img").attr("src",getImages());
    $(".box").hover(
        function(){ $(this).find(".overlay").fadeIn(); } ,
        function(){ $(this).find(".overlay").fadeOut(); }
    );        
}
```

I think your requested way doesn't work, because the browser expect a string for the source attribute.

P.S.: Take an eye on your random function. My Firefox did complain something "(missing ';' before statement")

Comment: Thanks, reporter. Not sure how to use this though

Comment: See the comment to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8211744/convert-milliseconds-or-seconds-into-human-readable-form/8211872#8211872 . It is a mathematical function. I could never find out the main meaning.

Comment: Reporter, that link doesn't provide a meaning. And, also, what is the notation `.box > .overlay > img` in `$(".box > .overlay > img").attr("src",getImages());` ?

Comment: The definition within the $() uses the normal css selector. So: find elements with class 'box'. Within that elements find elements with css class 'overlay' and within these, find elements with the html tag 'img'

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33994/discussion-between-growler-and-reporter)

Comment: reporter, is there a way to display all images in the array at once upon hover over?

Comment: I asked something in the chat

Answer (score 1):

You want to change the source of the image in your first hover function (the one with `fadeIn`).

Since you're already using jQuery, just do this:

```
    function(){ $(this img).attr("src", getImages()); $(this).find(".overlay").fadeIn(); } ,
```

and set your img's src initially to `""`.  Of course, you could simplify your jQuery if you added an `id` to the img tag.

**EDIT**
I set up a fiddle with a working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/uAG2j/).

This is the script code:

```
   var ITLP = [];
   ITLP[0] = "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/nature";
   ITLP[1] = "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/city";

   function getImages() {
       var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * (ITLP.length + 1)); // from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FMath%2Frandom
       console.log(ITLP[0]);
       return ITLP[0];
   }

   function showimg() {
       $(".box").hover(

       function () {
           console.log("Hover start");
           $(".box > .overlay > img").attr("src", getImages());
           $(this).find(".overlay").fadeIn();
       },

       function () {
           console.log("Hover end");
           $(this).find(".overlay").fadeOut();
       });
   }


   showimg();
```

Major things I did:

- Ordered the functions to be declared before they're used.
- Got rid of the `int i` declaration that was killing getImages()

To get it this far, I used the console log a lot, and also jsfiddle's JSHint is a big help.

Comment: Thanks Scott. Would I put the `function() { ...` directly inside the `$(document).ready(...`? I've set the img src initially to "", but it doesn't even seem to be showing the image, or working at all

Comment: Hi, Growler.  The line I gave you would replace the second line you have in your hover function.  Setting this binding during `document(ready)` as you have should be a good thing.  As reporter mentioned, you do have some bugs in the getImages() function.  That may be part of the issue you're having.  Check the console and see if it tells you anything.

Comment: @Growler Please check my edits, they should help you considerably.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this

```
var ImgArray = new Array();
// add images

$(document).ready(show);

// Show function
function show(){
    $('img').attr('src', ImgArray[0]).parent().hide();
    var max = ImgArray.length;
    $(".box").hover(
        function(){ $(this).find(".overlay").fadeIn(); },
        function(){ 
            var img = $(this).find(".overlay").find('img');
            var i = Math.floor(Math.random()*max);
            $(this).find(".overlay").fadeOut(function(){
                img.attr('src', ImgArray[i]);
            }); 
        }
    );        
}
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/JYnSY/1/)

Comment: is there a way to display all images in the array at once upon hover over?

Comment: At once, how ? One `img` can show on one image at a time, can you describe it ?