# Parse milliseconds to HH:MM:SS:UU by javascript or PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, datetime

I have integer milliseconds like 619308. How can I parse it  to format HH:MM:SS:UU by using Javascript or PHP ???

Sorry for my bad English

Comment: wow `619308` is small for miliseconds

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8212878/3660930

Comment: new Date(619308).toISOString().split("T")[1].slice(0,-1).replace(".",":") == "00:10:19:308"

Comment: Also http://php.net/date

Answer (score 0):

Your number is pretty small for milliseconds but...

Try this:

```
<?php

function formatp($input)
{
  $hours = (int)($minutes = (int)($seconds = (int)($milliseconds = (int)($input * 1000)) / 1000) / 60) / 60;
  return $hours.':'.($minutes%60).':'.($seconds%60).(($milliseconds===0)?'':'.'.rtrim($milliseconds%1000, '0'));
}

echo formatp(4.2225662134);
```

[Credits](http://www.jjask.com/120832/how-to-convert-microtime-to-hh-mm-ss-uu)

Answer (score 0):

Use [Date()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

var d = new Date( 619308 );
var curr_date = d.getDate();
var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1;
var curr_year = d.getFullYear();