# Comparing two Dates and returning in correct format

Tags: javascript, jquery, devextreme

I have a requirement where I need to compare two date values (Past Date and the Present Date) and return the exact difference in  year/month/day and if it exceeds 59 years 6 month even a single day then it should return over age else under age

I searched in web but not getting anything relevant to it.

Currently I am trying:

```
var start_date = new Date("1990-04-25");
    var end_date = new Date();
    var total_months = (end_date.getFullYear() - start_date.getFullYear())*12 + (end_date.getMonth() - start_date.getMonth());       
    if (total_months < 714) {
        alert("under age")
    } else { alert("over age") }
```

where I am converting the years to month, which is not giving me the exact result.

Can some one please help me to solve this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference in Months between two dates in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536379/difference-in-months-between-two-dates-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

```
var start_date = new Date("1990-04-25");
    var end_date = new Date();
    var millisec = Math.abs(end_date - start_date); // it will provide you miliseconds
// here you can convert it to days or month and check for over or under age
e.g 
        var seconds = (millisec / 1000).toFixed(1);

        var minutes = (millisec / (1000 * 60)).toFixed(1);

    var hours = (millisec / (1000 * 60 * 60)).toFixed(1);

    var days = (millisec / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)).toFixed(1);
```

for More help refer to these :
1. [How to subtract date/time in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4944750/how-to-subtract-date-time-in-javascript)
2. [Convert time interval given in seconds into more human readable form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8211744/convert-time-interval-given-in-seconds-into-more-human-readable-form)

Comment: Hello Pankaj, is it possible to return date as year=26,month=1,day=3 if I am subtracting two date for example  1990-04-25 and 2016-04-07.

Comment: var diff_in_days = (miliseconds / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
var diff_in_yrs = diff_in_days / 365; // final years
var remaining_days_yrs = diff_in_days % 365;
var diff_in_months = remaining_days / 12; // final months
var remaining_days_month = remaining_days % 12; // final days