# Unix seconds to clock/countdown format

Tags: php

I am currently trying to get a countdown clock using a unix timestamp value (remaining seconds) to H:M:S format, in order to sync my client side timers.

The value that I need to change to H:M:S has already been calculated as the time remaining in the countdown.

Let

```
$remaining_time
```

be our value of remaining seconds in the countdown.

Currently, here is what I have:

```
$H = floor($remaining_time / 3600);
$M = floor(($remaining_time - ($H*3600)) / 60);
$S = floor($remaining_time - ($H*3600 - ($M*60)));
```

I believe the hours/minutes is pretty close... but the seconds seems to be off. For example, I am getting results like this

```
$remaining_time = 4135;
```

Result: Time Remaining at price formatted: H:1 M:8 S:1015

Any information is appreciated - again, I need the remaining seconds in hours, minutes, and seconds.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert milliseconds into human readable form?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/175554/how-to-convert-milliseconds-into-human-readable-form)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`gmdate`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php), example:

```
<?php

$remaining_time = 4135;

echo "Time Remaining at price formatted: ".gmdate("\H:H \M:i \S:s",4135);

//Result: Time Remaining at price formatted: H:01 M:08 S:55
?>
```

Comment: And I can save each one as a variable? Example: $S = gmdate("\S:s", 4135); ?

Comment: `gmdate("s",4135)` will suffice