# JQuery - Formating milliseconds to HH:MM:SS:sss

Tags: jquery, milliseconds

I have trying to format a duration in milliseconds using this function but it's not working for me :

```
var msec_num      = parseInt(duration, 10) / 100; 
var hours        = Math.floor(msec_num / 3600 );
var minutes      = Math.floor((msec_num - (hours * 3600)) / 60);
var seconds      = Math.floor((msec_num - (hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60)) / 60 / 1000 );
var milliseconds = ( msec_num - ((hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60) - (seconds)) / 1000 ) * 100;

if (hours   < 10) {hours   = "0"+hours;}
if (minutes < 10) {minutes = "0"+minutes;}
if (seconds < 10) {seconds = "0"+seconds;}
if (milliseconds < 10) {milliseconds = "0"+milliseconds;}

var time    = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + ":" + milliseconds;
```

if I test using the value ( duration = 1091ms ) it gives to me this :  00:00:00:1091  ???

How I can figure out that all value work perfectly ??

Comment: jquery for date formatting - okay :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert milliseconds into human readable form?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/175554/how-to-convert-milliseconds-into-human-readable-form)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use "[duration](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/)" of [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) to make it easy!

```
var duration = moment.duration(parseInt(duration, 10));
var addZero = function(v) { return (v<10 ? '0' : '') + Math.floor(v); };

var time = addZero(duration.hours()) +
     ':' + addZero(duration.minutes()) +
     ':' + addZero(duration.seconds()) +
     ':' + addZero(duration.milliseconds());
```

Comment: How I can set format of milliseconds with 2 digits ??
Something like this -> if I have 192ms than show :19
                    -> if I have 82ms than show :08

Comment: Wooow it works, I have divided ( duration.milliseconds() / 10 ).
Thank's @Benjamin

Answer (score 2):

looks like you have problem with `100` instead of `1000`

```
var duration = 1091;
var milliseconds = (duration % 1000); duration = Math.floor(duration/1000);
var seconds = (duration % 60); duration = Math.floor(duration/60);
var minutes = (duration % 60); duration = Math.floor(duration/60);
var hours = duration;
```

Comment: @kach 1 second consist of 1000 miliseconds

Comment: @kach right, after manipulations above, duration will store only hours part

Comment: where is the subtraction of each milliseconds, seconds and minutes in var duration ? see my code how i did for that

Answer (score 1):

Try this - [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) - a javascript date library for parsing, validating, manipulating, and formatting dates.

Answer (score 0):

If I read the documentation of Moment.js it can be a lot easier:

```
moment(parseInt(duration, 10)).format('h:mm:ss');
```

Correct me if I'm wrong.