# Convert milliseconds to hours, min, and seconds python

Tags: python, function, datetime, time

I need to convert milliseconds to seconds minute hours. I have code like

```
def convertMillis(millis):
    seconds=(milli/1000)%60
    minutes=(milli/(1000*60))%60
    hours=(milli/(1000*60*60))%24

    return

def main():
    milli=print(input("Enter time in milliseconds "))

    print(hours,":",minutes,":",seconds

main()
```

But it's not a very good solution.

I would like to know the most pythonic way to do something like

```
>>> convertmillis(5500)
0:0:5
```

Comment: You left out the `)` at the end of your `print` call.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert milliseconds into human readable form?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/175554/how-to-convert-milliseconds-into-human-readable-form)

Comment: You can simplify `convertMillis()` by using `minutes, seconds = divmod(milli, 100)`, `hours, minutes = divmod(minutes, 60)`.  Also, you aren't returning anything.  You should say `return (hours, minutes, seconds)`.  Also, in `main()`, you define `milli` as the returns of `print()`.  `print()` always returns None.  You can just take the `print(` from the beginning and `)` from the end.  Also, to print it, use `print(":".join(convertMillis(int(milli))))`

Comment: `import datetime` then in your function: `duration = datetime.timedelta(milliseconds=millis)` and finally: `return (duration.hours, duration.minutes, duration.seconds)`

Comment: You should remove `% 24` for hours if you want a bigger number (i needed to count how many hours i worked and it was > 24)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If You want one single function:

```
millis=input("Enter time in milliseconds ")
millis = int(millis)
seconds=(millis/1000)%60
seconds = int(seconds)
minutes=(millis/(1000*60))%60
minutes = int(minutes)
hours=(millis/(1000*60*60))%24

print ("%d:%d:%d" % (hours, minutes, seconds))
```

Comment: not getting proper hours and getting 0 for minutes and seconds

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
 def convertMillis(millis):
     seconds=int(millis/1000)%60
     minutes=int(millis/(1000*60))%60
     hours=int(millis/(1000*60*60))%24
     return seconds, minutes, hours
 
 def main():
     millis=input("Enter time in milliseconds ")
     con_sec, con_min, con_hour = convertMillis(int(millis))
     print(f"{con_hour:02d}:{con_min:02d}:{con_sec:02d}")
 
 main()
```

The problems seem to be:

1. You lack the understanding of local and global variables. Just because a variable is in your `convertMillis` doesn't mean `main` will get to read it. You have to explicitly return them.
2. You misunderstood the syntax of `print`, `input` and `return`

Comment: Why not take advantage of `divmod()`?