# How to convert milliseconds to time

Tags: python

I want to convert milliseconds to time. Please help me in that

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.parser import parse

current = datetime.now()
print(current)

milli = current.microsecond
print(milli)
```

Comment: This is a answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35989666/convert-milliseconds-to-hours-min-and-seconds-python

Comment: what is **TIME** in your context? Hour minutes seconds? or a timestamp like year-month-date Hour-min-seconds or something else?

Comment: The shown code does not help to understand your question.  `mili` here is just the microsecond part of `current` and you cannot rebuild hour, minutes or seconds from it. I am sorry but this question is *unclear*.

Comment: I want to convert milliseconds to time

Comment: ok i will check, Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean milliseconds to time?
If you want datetime format, use

```
timenow=datetime.timedelta(milliseconds=999999)

print(timenow)
```

the output is

```
0:16:39.999000
```