# calculate number of minutes by passing Milliseconds

Tags: python, django, time, minute

**I have used following to get number of minutes by passing Milliseconds**

```
def returnTimeString(miliSec):
    returnVal = "%d" % (  ((miliSec / 1000) / 60) )
    if returnVal == '0':
        returnVal = 'N/A'
    return returnVal
```

**But I want different way then this to fetch number of minutes by passing Milliseconds**

Answer (score 2):

here is what you need

```
minutes=float(miliSec/float(1000*60))%60.
```

simple and elegant

Answer (score 0):

milliseconds to minutes

```
y = miliSec / 1000
y /= 60
minutes = y % 60
```

Oneliner

```
minutes=(miliSec/(1000*60))%60
```

Final result:

```
def returnTimeString(miliSec):
    minutes=(miliSec/(1000*60))%60
    return "%d" % (minutes) if minutes else 'N/A'
```

Comment: i want Milliseconds to minutes conversion

Comment: @O.T. fixed, check it out.

Answer (score -1):

Here is another solution based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/175576/6607630) that gives you the conversion from milliseconds to seconds, minutes, and days.

```
def millitosec(milliseconds):
   x = milliseconds / 1000 
   seconds = x % 60
   x /= 60
   minutes = x % 60
   x /= 60
   hours = x % 24
   x /= 24
   days = x
   return seconds, minutes, hours, days
```

Comment: Please don't post link only answers to other Stack Overflow questions. Instead, vote/flag to close as duplicate, or, if the question is not a duplicate, *tailor the answer to this specific question.*

Comment: It was valid Question, i was expecting different solution for my result