# Microseconds to human readable output

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have a need to convert microseconds to a human readable format. While I would be able convert it to HH:MM:SS.MS, I'm not sure the best way to strip the 00:'s if present I would like work with these

```
input = [ 12040000, 60042000, 15582000000 ]
output = [ '12.04', '1:00.42', '4:19:27' ]

function formatMark(mu) {
    var timeList = []
    var ms = mu / 1000
    var time = new Date(ms)

    var ms = time.getMilliseconds()
    var ss = time.getSeconds()
    var mm = time.getMinutes()
    var hh = time.getHours()

    if (ms > 1) timeList.push(ms) //
    if (ss > 1) timeList.push(ss) // 
    if (mm > 1) timeList.push(mm) //
    if (hh > 1) timeList.push(hh) //

    return { hh + ':' + mm + ':' + ss + '.' + ms }

 }
```

Unfortunately the code above doesn't work, probably for multiple reasons in which I'd be better off knowing, but I really just need a conventional and readable output. Any tips / suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert milliseconds into human readable form?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/175554/how-to-convert-milliseconds-into-human-readable-form)

Comment: Microseconds? You know that micro is 10^-3 milli, don't you?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado easy... Be nice to the new guys.

Comment: try new Date(15582000000 )

Comment: Now I see that he's in fact dividing by 1000 and the question's title refers to the input only. I was confused because he's not returning the microseconds, while the question's title may imply returning the microseconds as well.

Answer (score 0):

> Unfortunately the code above doesn't work, probably for multiple
>   reasons in which I'd be better off knowing,

Syntax of your `return` statement is wrong

Try replacing your `return` statement with

```
return { hh : hh, mm : mm, ss : ss, ms : ms }
```

Finally, use the output of `formatMark` as

```
var output = formatMark(157442234333332221);
var finalOutput = Object.keys( output ).map( function( key ){ return key + ":" + output[key] } ).join(",");
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your question, you are passing parameter as array type but the function is not compatible to handle this, your logic for calculating readable time string is correct. only thing is that you need to handle this for array type parameter.

```
function formatMark(mu) {
     var timeList = []
     mu.map(function(t){
           var ms = mu / 1000
           var time = new Date(ms)
           var ms = time.getMilliseconds()
           var ss = time.getSeconds()
           var mm = time.getMinutes()
           var hh = time.getHours()

           if (ms > 1) timeList.push(ms) //
           if (ss > 1) timeList.push(ss) // 
           if (mm > 1) timeList.push(mm) //
           if (hh > 1) timeList.push(hh) //
           var timeString=hh + ':' + mm + ':' + ss + '.' + ms 
           console.log(timeString)
           timeList.push(timeString)
      })
      return timeList;
}
```

This function accepts array and returns the array of readable time strings.