# Is there a more efficient way to convert milliseconds to this format "{minutes}:{seconds}"?

Tags: python

This is different from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175554/how-to-convert-milliseconds-into-human-readable-form).

I am working on converting milliseconds to this format "{minutes}:{seconds}" in Python.

I've already implement this conversion

```
duration_in_ms = 350001
x = duration_in_ms / 1000
seconds = x % 60
x /= 60
'{}:{}'.format(str(int(x)).zfill(2), round(seconds,3))
```

the output is

```
'05:50.001'
```

is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: minutes, seconds = divmod(duration_in_ms/1000 , 60)

Comment: I don't see anything particularly wrong with your current implementation.  Wrap it up in a function, write some unit test and you're good to go! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use an f-string:

```
duration = 350001
minutes, seconds = divmod(duration / 1000, 60)

f'{minutes:0>2.0f}:{seconds:.3f}'
```

Output:

```
'05:50.001'
```

Answer (score 1):

There you go:

```
import datetime
duration_in_ms = 350001
print(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(duration_in_ms/1000.0).strftime('%M:%S.%f')[:-3])
```

Example:

```
Python 3.6.1 (default, Dec 2015, 13:05:11)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux

> import datetime
> duration_in_ms = 350001
> print(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(duration_in_ms/1000.0).strftime('%M:%S.%f')[:-3])
05:50.001
```

Comment: That gave output as `35:50.001`. Is something wrong?

Comment: I'm getting the right output, updated my answer with example, tested it with [repl](https://repl.it/languages/python3).

Comment: Sorry about that. I see now that it works on the online IDEs. I have no idea why it doesn't work on my system.

Comment: That's weird, I've tested it on my system too with both Python 3.6 and 2.7. Getting the correct output everywhere. If you do ever find out why you're getting `35:50.001` please let me know :D

Comment: Sure thing. I too am wondering why it's so. And I've tried on a fresh python3.7 as well.