# How to convert ms to time with Python?

Tags: python, time

How can I convert a number of ms to a date format like : HH/MM/SS/MS

For example, if I have 1900ms, I want to have:
0h 0min 1s 900ms

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: 190 ms is 0.19 seconds, not 1s 90ms.

Comment: oh snap, just missed that too. I thought it was in seconds.

Comment: Yes sorry ! @AKX

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a more efficient way to convert milliseconds to this format "{minutes}:{seconds}"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56286822/is-there-a-more-efficient-way-to-convert-milliseconds-to-this-format-minutes)

Comment: Also see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42320260/17242583

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `timedelta()` option from the datetime library. An example of it is:

```
import datetime

print(str(datetime.timedelta(milliseconds=600000)))
```

You can also use days, minutes, seconds instead of milliseconds. Link to the official documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta

Comment: The format is  0:05:33.150000 not 00:05:33.150

Answer (score 0):

You can use datetime to convert milliseconds in timestamp

```
import datetime    
datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ms/1000.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure - `divmod` to the rescue:

```
def ms_to_hmsms(total_ms):
    rest, ms = divmod(int(total_ms), 1000)
    rest, s = divmod(rest, 60)
    rest, m = divmod(rest, 60)
    rest, h = divmod(rest, 60)
    return f"{h}h {m}min {s}s {ms}ms"


print(ms_to_hmsms(1900))
print(ms_to_hmsms(91462322926))
```

This prints out

```
0h 0min 1s 900ms
26h 12min 2s 926ms
```